# Pass value from table controller using anchor tag

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CI.. I want to pass an id from table using anchor tag... but I can't pass maybe my code is not correct.

View . . . . .

```
    <?php
    foreach ($records as $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align=center >" . $value -> id . "</td>";
        echo "<td align=center >" . $value -> name . "</td>";
        echo "<td align=center >" . $value -> lastname . "</td>";
        echo "<td align=center >" . $value -> classlevel . "</td>";
        echo "<td align=center >" . $value -> mobileno . "</td>";
        echo "<td align=center >" . $value -> address . "</td>";
        echo "<td align=center >" . anchor('StudentController/del_record/'.$value->id ,'Delete') . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

Controller....

```
public function del_record($value) {
    $data = array('id' => $this -> input -> post('$value->id'));
    if ($data = $this -> Student_Model -> del_record($data)) {
        echo "The operation has been successfully completed";
    } else {
        echo "query not run";
    }
}
```

`

I am waiting for your response...

Comment: Can you provide an example output?

Comment: please check it again

Comment: cant asign id to $data... please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you are trying to pass the ID to delete via GET (in the URL). You can accessing this via $value inside your function declaration. As you are passing a single value (the ID)  you don't need to need to access it as if it were and object.

Change this:

```
$data = array('id' => $this -> input -> post('$value->id'));
```

to this:

```
 $data = array('id' => $this -> input -> post('$value'));
```